# Executing a PHP script at a certain time on a shared hosting

Tags: php, cron, twitter-oauth

I'm testing with a PHP script which has a an array of dynamic time table (times will change each day accordingly). What this script does is that, whenever one of these times matches the array, it will send out a tweet to a specific twitter account using its defined API keys. But it happens manually as I have to access the php file each time to match both array and server time. If explain more;

> **Example:** If array **A** = 12:00pm & if I access the PHP file when the current server time matches the array (if also 12:00pm), it will post a tweet.

I don't want to check this array always and run php file each time just to send a tweet. Also, when I check with my hosting to run a cronjob they says the minimum time is 15 minutes, as that is a restriction for shared hosting. Is there any other solution which I can go for??

**P.S.:** I did not post any of those scripts as it works perfectly but the only problem is executing it. If there are any other fixes where you will be needing to see the codes. I can post it in here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try one of these web services:

- https://www.easycron.com/
- https://www.setcronjob.com/

Answer (score 0):

shared server will normally limit the number and time interval for execution of cron. This is normal. Try to find out for a dedicated server which allow more cron

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't just expect to buy a dedicated server simply to run a cron or may be there'll be a solution to overcome this.. will see..